# Socket.io Chat Tutorial not functioning properly

Tags: node.js, socket.io

So I finally decided to give Node.js a shot. I decided to go with a small chat app to break the ice. The tutorial I am following is directly from the socket.io site.

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I am following the tutorial word for word and have even tried to copy and paste the code into the source and am getting no where when I type in text and send it. It is supposed to be coming up in my command prompt, however it is not.

I had the user connected and user disconnected messages appear but I am stumped on this one as I have followed the tutorial step by step.

Index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile('/chat/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function() {
   console.log('Listening on *:3000');
});
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chat</title>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();
        $('form').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
        body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
        form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
        form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
        form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
        #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
        #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <ul id="messages"></ul>

    <form action="">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am assuming I fouled up some where but am not seeing it, even though I did try and copy and paste it. Also, if it matters I am using Windows 8.1 and Chrome. I checked around and could find no answer to this problem as well. Any help would be great.

EDIT: The problem was with jQuery, for some reason it is not responding as it should. After rewriting the script in vanilla it works as intended.

Index.js - JavaScript

```
<script>
    var socket = io();

    function sendMessage() {
        var msg = document.getElementById('m');

        socket.emit('message', msg.value);
        msg.value = '';
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" onsubmit="javascript:sendMessage();">
        <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide any server and client-side console output?

Comment: No errors on either side. Thats what Im finding frustrating.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can activate logging for Socket.IO in Chrome by typing in your console :

```
localStorage.debug = "socket.io-client:socket"
```

and on the server side :

```
DEBUG=* node yourfile.js
```

Also, you want the script to be executed when the document is ready, in order to use jQuery so you need to delay it a bit :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var socket = io();
   $('form').submit(function(){
       socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
       $('#m').val('');
       return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: I am only getting "socket.io-client:socket transport is open - connecting +0ms". Nothing else. All of this is running on localhost.

Comment: what about the server side?

Comment: "break in index.js:1"

Comment: The problem seems to be with jQuery. The events are not working properly. I tried a simple click event ($('#button').click()) and it did not display an alert or log to the console. I then made a JavaScript function and added some inline code to the button (onclick) and it did both the alert and logged to the console. Any idea why jQuery would be acting this way?

Comment: I wonder why the tutorial would not dictate that, oh well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: did it work? I'll create an issue on github so they can fix it if so

Comment: @xShirase @Joe - I am also facing the same problem. I have already added everything inside the `$(document).ready(function(){....}` , still I get nothing printed on the client side,i.e. the `JS` code is not getting executed. Is there anything else that can be done to solve this issue

Answer (score 7):

A little after the fact, but I had the same issue and tied it back to a load order issue. Just move the code that is binding to the form to the bottom of `<body>` rather than in `<head>`. It's a little misleading as some of the earlier code in the tutorial was directly in `<head>`.